# How to disable .xaml.cs nesting in Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, xaml

How can I disable the nesting of .xaml.cs files under their .xaml counterparts in the solution explorer?

Obviously I still want the linkage between the two, but I'm sick of having to go an extra level deeper to get to my code behind files.

Large project. Tons of these pairs. Way too much hassle to get at the files I need to get at frequently.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to your .xaml and double-click in it.

Press F7 and you'll go directly in your codebehind.

Now, if you really want to disable the nesting rule for files, you can follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2022#disable-file-nesting-rules-for-a-project